# Parent action prevents from submit action from ever being called in ember.js

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js, action

I have a div. That div has an action. The div also has a form tag as a child. That form tag has an on submit action. While there is an action on my div the form submit action is never called. Is this correct?

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jeyaxodugi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

In the above fiddle try removing the div's action and then the form submit action will work fine. How can I ensure that both actions are called not just the parent.

Answer (score 2):

By default the action helper will call `Event#preventDefault` so when you click in the submit button, the `divClick` is executed, preventDefault is called and as a consequence `formSubmit` will not be called. To avoid this you can use the option `preventDefault=false` like `{{ action "divClick" preventDefault=false}}>`. 
After this you will notice that both `divClick` and `formSubmit` will be triggered if you click in the submit button, this happen because the click event bubbles from the button to the div, if you don't want this behavior you can use `bubbles=false` in your submit button, like the following `<input type="submit" value="submit" {{action "formSubmit" bubbles=false}}>`

This is the final code

```
<div id="my-div" {{ action "divClick" preventDefault=false}}>
  Hello World
  <form {{action "formSubmit" on="submit" }}>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" {{action "formSubmit" bubbles=false}}>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the updated jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/doroqocafu/1/edit?html,js,output

You can find more info about this in [action helper docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_event-propagation)

I hope it helps